# problems adding an App Engine app to a Google Apps domains

Tags: google-app-engine

We have been adding domains to our app without any issues for past couple months, following these instructions https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains

Since yesterday we have not been able to, when clicking Activate this service we get this error message
"An error occurred while trying to install this application. Please try again later."

We have tried this also with older domains and with different apps and getting the same error, so the problem seems to be more widespread, not isolated to particular domains / apps.

Does anyone know how to solve?

Thanks
Ron

Comment: I have exactly the same problem: I noticed yesterday because I was migrating to an HRD new project

Comment: Same problem here, the domains I added before still work, but I can't create new app ids to a newly verified domain.

Comment: Has anyone ever resolved this?  I'm curious if the problem just goes away eventually.

Answer (score 1):

In the Google Apps control panel, click on "Domain Settings", scroll down to "New Admin Control Panel Features" and select "Current Release (multiple languages)".

Then try again to add your app engine id at https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/YOURSITE.TLD/SelectServices

This worked for me.

Also see
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps/control-panel/k2Ecis3paW4